# Creating two dimensional arraylist using java

Tags: java

I want to add values in two dimensional arraylist using java. I am using this code

```
public abstract class TwoDimensionalArrayList {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> twoDimensional=new ArrayList<>();
    oneDimensional.add(new ArrayList<String>());
    int value=0;
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<3;j++) {
            twoDimensional.get(i).add(value+"");
            value++;
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<3;j++) {
            System.out.println(twoDimensional.get(i).get(j));
        }
    }
}
```

}

I want to output as

```
twoDimensional={{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}
```

when i run my code i am getting error like this.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1
at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:248)
at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:373)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:425)
at TwoDimensionalArrayList.main(TwoDimensionalArrayList.java:11)
```

Please anyone help me

Comment: You only added one element to the outer list. There's nothing at index 1.

Comment: You will need to create the individual ArrayList<String> 's that are the rows. The original twoDimensional list is empty.

Comment: This code doesn't compile because `oneDimensional` is not declared anywhere, but you must add the three lists to `twoDimensional`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that there's a typo in the code, and that `oneDimensional.add(...)` should actually be `twoDimensional.add(...)` in which case, the first loop runs from i=0 to i=2, but you've only added one ArrayList to twoDimensional. This triggers an IndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: Thanks bro, actually that is twoDimensional.add(...) only, i have used in code like this only.